# foreach loops in controller

Tags: php, laravel, foreach, controller

I've nearly 6 foreach loops in controller. I'm rendering data from an API. Will the foreach loops make the system slow? Cause the view is taking longer time to display. If so, what steps do I need to take to reduce the number of foreach loops? 
Thanks.

Comment: Put your code so we can help you

Comment: How are we going to help you if you have not provided any code ?

Comment: Your API should be broken down to receive different resources and to be handled separately. You got one API endpoint that receives multiple things then your controller has to process those in multiple foreach. This will defiantly slow down your response time.

Comment: The 3 inner loops after the for can be removed and you dont need a continue statement